# Configuration and content management with automated deployment tools for ZF based app

Tags: zend-framework, deployment, automation, capistrano, phing

I am trying to automate deployments of a particular project and a bit lost as to who to handle config file as well as user assets.
(Application is based on Zend Framework based btw).

Main application folder is structured as follows:

```
./app
     ./config.ini   <----- config file
     ./modules
     ./controllers
     ./models
     ./views
./libs
./public
```

That config file is where all the configs are stored.
So 'app' folder contains whole bunch of code in PHP and 'public' contains whole bunch of code in JavaScript, HTML/CSS and stuff like that(web accessible basically).

If I follow Capistrano's model, where each package is expanded into it's own folder that is then symlinked to, how do I handle that config.ini file? 
What about all the user content that is uploaded into ./public folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Capistrano approach to this is to have a structure like this on your remote server:

```
releases/
    20100901172311/
    20101001101232/
    [...]
current/ (symlink to current release)
shared/
```

in the shared directory you include your config file and any user generated content (e.g. `shared/files`). Then on each deployment, once you've checked out the code you automatically create symlinks from the checkout into your relevant shared directories. E.g.:

```
releases/20101001101232/public/files -> shared/files
releases/20101001101232/application/configs/config.ini -> shared/config.ini
```

that way, when a user uploads a file to `public/files` it is actually being stored in `shared/files`.